# A question on projective unitary representation of a Lie group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, hilbert-spaces, unitary-representations

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $\GL(\mathcal{H})$ denote the group of invertible linear transformations of $\mathcal{H}$. Assume that $G=\{ f:\mathbb{P}\mathcal{H}\to \mathbb{P}\mathcal{H}|f\; \text{is a symmetry}\}$ (where $\mathbb{P}\mathcal{H}$ is the projective space).

A map $T:G\to \GL(\mathcal{H})$ is called a projective representation if $T(f)\circ T(g)=e^{C(f,g)}T(f\circ g)$ for all $f,g\in G$, where $C:G\times G\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function. The representation $T$ is called exact if $T(f)\circ T(g)=T(f\circ g)$ for all $f,g\in G$. I have a question concerning this statement that I found in the book "BMS Particles in Three Dimensions" by B. OBLAK, page 20:

> "Let $G$ be not simply connected. Any one-dimensional unitary representation of the fundamental group of $G$, multiplying an exact unitary representation of $G$, produces a projective unitary representation of $G$".

I have tried to prove this but I couldn't. I have also tried in the opposite way.

**My try**: Let $T$ be a (continuous) projective unitary representation of $G$. Since $G$ is not simply connected, then there exists a closed path $\gamma$ in $\pi_1 (G)$ at some point $f\in G$. Since $T$ is projective, we have $T(\gamma (1))=e^{i\phi (\gamma)}T(\gamma (0))$. Clearly, the map $\pi_1 (G)\to \mathbb{C}^*$ by $[\gamma]\to e^{i\phi (\gamma)}$ is a one-dimensional unitary representation of the fundamental group of $G$. But I couldn't find an exact unitary representation of $G$.

Comment: "$GL(\mathcal{H})$ denote the group of invertible linear transformations": do you mean continuous ones?

Comment: @YCor In the book, the author has just mentioned that the map $G\times \mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}:(f,\Psi)\mapsto T(f)\cdot \Psi$  is continuous (all representations are continuous).

Comment: Indeed, this implies that $T$ takes value in the group of bi-continuous invertible operators (but doesn't say explicitly what is meant by GL, although one can guess it means only bi-continuous ones).

Comment: @YCor Yes, you are right.

Comment: @YCor If we have an exact representation (I mean $T:G\to GL(\mathcal{H})$ is a homomorphism) and $[\gamma ]\in \pi_1 (G)$ is non-trivial, then can we construct a projective representation of $G$?